# rendering the html component via filter method

Tags: angular

I am trying to render my table data so that upon searching the specific title the only title that matches it gets displayed (searching is done by title)

html component

```
<button type="button" mdbBtn color="primary" mdbWavesEffect 
[routerLink]="['new']">New Products</button>

<form class="form-inline md-form form-sm active-pink-5" 
(ngSubmit)="onsubmit()"  #f="ngForm">

<div class="md-form form-group mt-12">
<input mdbInputDirective type="text" class="form-control" 
id="formGroupExampleInputMD" placeholder="Search"
name="search" required ngModel #search="ngModel">

<button type="submit" mdbBtn color="primary" style="position: 
absolute; left: -9999px" mdbWavesEffect>Search</button>

</div>
</form>
<table mdbTable>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let head of headElements" scope="col">{{head}} </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr mdbTableCol *ngFor="let el of listofproducts;let id=index">
      <td>{{id}}</td>
    <td >{{el.title}}</td>
    <td>{{el.price}}</td>
    <td class="edit" (click)="onclickedit(id)">Edit</td>

  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So here i want to display only those table data whoose value matches from the value entered in the serach box (searching is done acc. to title)

.ts component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Productservice } from 'src/app/shared/product.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Items } from 'src/app/shared/items.modal';

@Component({
selector: 'app-admin-products',
templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.scss']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private prservice:Productservice,private 
route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) { }

listofproducts
productreceived
headElements = ['S.No' ,'Title', 'Price'];


ngOnInit() {
 this.listofproducts=this.prservice.getallproducts()

 }

itemlist
 @ViewChild('f') searchform:NgForm



onsubmit(){
let search=this.searchform.value
this.itemlist=this.prservice.getallproducts()
 let  titles=this.itemlist.map(i=>i.title);


let found2 = titles.filter(title => title.includes(search.search))


console.log(found2)

}


}
```

I have been able to console log my desired results in the console now how to implement this in my html component ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for the simple title search you are implementing would be changing the list you are binding on the *ngFor , in your case listofproducts. But when you remove the search it wont restore back the old ones you had so what you should do instead is create another variable and by default have the same values as listofproducts but when you submit the text filter you change the variable to your filter
Example:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Productservice } from 'src/app/shared/product.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Items } from 'src/app/shared/items.modal';

@Component({
selector: 'app-admin-products',
templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.scss']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private prservice:Productservice,private 
route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) { }

listofproducts
filteredproducts
productreceived
headElements = ['S.No' ,'Title', 'Price'];


ngOnInit() {
 this.listofproducts=this.prservice.getallproducts();
 this.filteredproducts = this.listofproducts;
 }

itemlist
 @ViewChild('f') searchform:NgForm



onsubmit(){
let search=this.searchform.value
this.itemlist=this.prservice.getallproducts()
 let  titles=this.itemlist.map(i=>i.title);


this.filteredproducts = titles.filter(title => title.includes(search.search))

}


}
```

Then on the html change the 'listofproducts' for 'filteredproducts' and when you want to remove the text filter just change the filteredproducts value back to listofproducts